# Can't change App Name for Google authentication using Omniauth for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, omniauth

I've set up my my omniauth.rb file using

provider :google

but whenever I try to login, I still get "The site 934189150838.apps.googleusercontent.com is requesting access to your Google Account for the product(s) listed below. "

What am I missing? I've changed my branding information on the Google API Console...